# How do I handle values that are dependent on the result of a helper?

Tags: meteor, angular-meteor

So I have an Angular controller with a meteor helper method, as below.

```
function localeCtrl($scope, $reactive, $stateParams{
    $reactive(this).attach($scope);
    var self = this;
    self.helpers({
        locale: function(){ return Locales.findOne($stateParams.id)},
        staff: function(){
            // Load data from second collection based on current Locale.
            // But how?
        },
        address: function(){
            // Take self.location.address and massage it to provide
            // google maps link.  How?
        }
        tags: function(){
            // Collect all unique instances of a given tag by
            // iterating over the available locales.
            // E. G. If 10 locales have the 'restaurant' tag, and 5
            // more have the 'library' tag, I want an array of
            // ['restaurant', 'library'] -- easy enough to do
            // by iterating over the locales, but how do I do that
            // reactively?
        }
    });
}
```

Unfortunately, I need to set additional properties *based* on the data fetched by locale().  I can't set them up when I initialize the controller because the value in locale() changes as data is fetched from the server.  But I need access to the data in locale to, for example, create the google maps address, or fetch associated records.  (They aren't imbedded in the locale document for reasons that I'm sure made sense at the time).

Edit:

Additionally, I'm using ground DB to store a local copy of the data for offline access, which makes life even more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you best bet is to publish your collection using [publishComposite](https://guide.meteor.com/data-loading.html#publishing-relations) which is implemented using the [reywood:publish-composite](https://atmospherejs.com/reywood/publish-composite) package.

Add the package:

```
meteor add reywood:publish-composite
```

Now where you publish the Locales collection you would do something like this:

```
Meteor.publishComposite('locales', function() {
 return {
    find() {
      //Put whatever you need in the query for locales
      const query = {
        _userId: this.userId
      };


      return Locales.find(query);
    },

    children: [{
      find(locale) {
        return Staff.find({ localeId: locale._id });
      }
    }]
  };
});
```

Then in your controller before the helper you add this:

```
this.subscribe('locales');
```

Now you should be able to simply call the code like this:

```
 this.helpers({
        locale(){
            return Locales.findOne(this.$stateParams.id);
        }
    });
```

And access it in the template like this:

```
 locale.staff
```

Give that a try and let me know!

Comment: Unfortunately, some of the key logic is backwards.  (Don't blame me, I came in late in development).  Staff IDs are stored on the locale.  (Edit:  Actually, I think I see how to adjust for that now, on second read)  Another issue is that I'm using ground DB for an offline mode, and I'm not sure that cooperates with what you're suggesting.  We'll see how it works once I fix a few other things.

Comment: Also, I added an additional use-case issue that I _think_ your advice covers.  Should be as simple as a 'children' method that just has the logic covering the transformation, I think... right?

Comment: I think you should be able to add another children collection and simply reference it just like you would the staff. I would look at the docs of the links that I referenced to be sure. It sounds like you're on the right path. :)

Comment: I'm updating the question again with another use-case issue.

Comment: Have you tried using the publishComposite?  The pattern should solve most of your problems.  The other part with the tags could be created as aggregate items in mongoDB.  If you go to the reywood examples (see the links above) it gives you examples.  Follow the topTenPosts and that is similar to the tags.

Comment: you're right, we can solve a lot of problems by just changing the data on the server.  Just didn't want to bite that particular bullet if I didn't have to, but at this point... time to just rewrite the server code so it serves up the correct, useful data instead of junk.